# Validate is never called in self-hosted wcf service?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I am calling my service like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       TestServiceClient client = new  
 TestServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_ITestService");
       client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "wrong";
       client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

        try
        {
            client.Open();

            client.GetColors(); //should not validate, but it is.
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I am overriding Validate like this:

```
public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {

        if ((userName != "right") || (password != "password"))
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Validation Failed!");
        }
    }

    public CustomUserNameValidator()
    {


    }
}
```

CustomUserNameValidator is in my Test.dll, so in my web.configs ServiceBehehaviors section, I have this defined:

```
<behavior name="CustomValidator">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                 customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Test.CustomUserNameValidator, Test"/>

        <serviceCertificate findValue="Test" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>

        </serviceCredentials>

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>

    </behavior>
```

When I run the client, it executes the service fine even though I gave it the wrong credentials. Validate doesn't even get called.  The only way I can get Validate to be called is if I put it in my Operation GetColors, but then I would have to put it in every operation.

I have my users stored in a table with username and an an encrypted password, so is a custom username/password validator the way to go or should I approach it differently.

Does custom username validation work if it is not self-hosted, but hosted in IIS?

Comment: A small typo will faul this up, and we're missing the link-up from the binding to the behaviour.

Comment: Custom username validation *does* work with self-hosting. Could you post the binding configuration?

Comment: @Pedro,  I actually got it to work.  I believe it was a binding configuration.